# Como calculo los aciertos en una combinación

Tags: java

Tengo que calcular los aciertos en una combinación y no sé cómo hacerlo. ¿Alguna ayuda?

El enunciado es :

> Éste método nos va a servir para calcular qué premio ha obtenido el
>   usuario jugador. Para ello, debemos pasarle los dos arrays que
>   calculamos en los dos métodos anteriores. Dentro de método, debemos
>   comparar los 6 primeros valores de array que apostó el usuario con los
>   primeros 6 valores los valores del array que salieron en el bombo
>   aleatorio. El último valor de cada array nos sirve para el reintegro
>   que tiene un valor de premio distinto de los demás y por ello hay que
>   tratarlo por separado. Cada vez que se detecte un valor acertado, se
>   le sumará a los que ya pudiera tener, hay que ir acumulando el premio
>   en una variable para después ser devuelta al final del método.

Y este es el código que tengo:

```
     private void init(){
       System.out.println("***** PRIMITIVA ******");

       int[] apuesta = introducirApuesta();

       int[] combinacionGanadora = calcularCombinacionGanadora();

       if (combinacionGanadora!=null) {
           System.out.println("La combinacion ganadora es: ");
           for (int i = 0; i < combinacionGanadora.length - 1; i++) {
               System.out.print(combinacionGanadora[i] + " ");
           }
           System.out.println("Reintegro: " + combinacionGanadora[combinacionGanadora.length - 1]);
       }

       int premio = comprobarAciertos(apuesta, combinacionGanadora);
       System.out.println("Tu premio es: "+premio+" €");


   }



   public int[] introducirApuesta(){
       Random rnd=new Random();
       Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
       int random = 0;

       System.out.println("Introduce tu apuesta");
       int [] apuesta=new int[6];

           for (int i=0;i<apuesta.length;i++){
             apuesta[i]=input.nextInt();
           }

       System.out.println("La Apuesta introducida es");
       random=rnd.nextInt(9);
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(apuesta)+" "+random);

       return apuesta;
   }

   public boolean disponible(int numero, int[] tomados){
       for(int i = 0; i < tomados.length; i++){
           if(numero == tomados[i]){
               return false;
           }
       }
       return true;
   }

  public int[] calcularCombinacionGanadora(){
       int [] combinacion=new int[6];
       int numero;
       //Inicializando el array
       for(int i=0; i < 6; i++){
           combinacion[i] = -1;
       }
       //Rellenando el array
       for(int i=0; i < 6; i++){
           numero = (int)(Math.random() * 49 + 1);
           while(!disponible(numero, combinacion)){
               numero = (int)(Math.random() * 49 + 1);
           }
           combinacion[i] = numero;
       }
       combinacion[5] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
       return combinacion;
   }

   public int comprobarAciertos(int[] apuesta, int[] combinacionGanadora) {
       int premio = 0;
       int aciertos = 0;
       //Comprobar aciertos en combinación
       for (int i=0;i<apuesta.length -1;i++) {
           if ( apuesta[0] == combinacionGanadora[0] ) {
               premio++;
           }
       }

        boolean reintegro = (apuesta[6] == combinacionGanadora[6]);

       return premio;
   }
   }
```

Comment: ¡Hola! Comparte el código que has intentado para poder ayudarte. Por el contrario, la pregunta terminará cerrada por ser demasiado amplia. Las preguntas que son solo enunciados no se ven bien en el sitio. Considera leer [ask] y [help/dont-ask] para más información

Comment: Voy lo cuelgo ahora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola buenas tardes te dejo mi código donde valido los aciertos espero que te sea util.

```
package patofer;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Azar {
    public static <T> void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("***** PRIMITIVA ******");

        int[] apuesta = introducirApuesta();

        int[] combinacionGanadora = calcularCombinacionGanadora();

        if (combinacionGanadora!=null) {
            System.out.println("La combinacion ganadora es: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < combinacionGanadora.length - 1; i++) {
                System.out.print(combinacionGanadora[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("Reintegro: " + combinacionGanadora[combinacionGanadora.length - 1]);
        }

        int premio = comprobarAciertos(apuesta, combinacionGanadora);
        System.out.println("Tu premio es: "+premio+" €");


    }



    public static int[] introducirApuesta(){
        Random rnd=new Random();
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int random = 0;

        System.out.println("Introduce tu apuesta");
        int [] apuesta=new int[6];

        for (int i=0;i<apuesta.length;i++){
            apuesta[i]=input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("La Apuesta introducida es");
        random=rnd.nextInt(9);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(apuesta)+" "+random);

        return apuesta;
    }

    public static boolean disponible(int numero, int[] tomados){
        for(int i = 0; i < tomados.length; i++){
            if(numero == tomados[i]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static int[] calcularCombinacionGanadora(){
        int [] combinacion=new int[6];
        int numero;
        //Inicializando el array
        for(int i=0; i < 6; i++){
            combinacion[i] = -1;
        }
        //Rellenando el array
        for(int i=0; i < 6; i++){
            System.out.println("---> random "+Math.random());
            numero = (int)(Math.random() * 49 + 1);
            while(!disponible(numero, combinacion)){
                numero = (int)(Math.random() * 49 + 1);
            }
            combinacion[i] = numero;
        }
        combinacion[5] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        return combinacion;
    }

    public static int comprobarAciertos(int[] apuesta, int[] combinacionGanadora) {
        int premio = 0;
        int aciertos = 0;
        //Comprobar aciertos en combinación
        for (int i=0;i<apuesta.length -1;i++) {
            for (int x=0;x<combinacionGanadora.length -1;x++) {
                if(combinacionGanadora[x] == apuesta[i]){
                    // en este punto asignar el monto del premio
                    premio+=20;
                }
            }
        }

        return premio+=validaReintegro(apuesta, combinacionGanadora);
    }


    public static int validaReintegro(int[] apuesta, int[] combinacionGanadora){
        System.out.println("valor de reintegro  ingresado "+apuesta[apuesta.length-1]);
        System.out.println("valor de reintegro  ingresado  al azar "+combinacionGanadora[combinacionGanadora.length-1]);
        if(apuesta[apuesta.length-1] == combinacionGanadora[combinacionGanadora.length-1]){
            //el valor que retornes en este punto, es el valor de premio de reintegro
            return 11;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

cuando el reintegro son iguales se le asigna un valor de 2 para diferenciarlo

salida por pantalla

***** PRIMITIVA ******
Introduce tu apuesta
2
22
32
25
24
29
La Apuesta introducida es
[2, 22, 32, 25, 24, 29] 2
La combinación ganadora es: 
24 48 29 6 31 Reintegro: 1
Tu premio es: 1 €

como se puede ver ingrese el 29 el cual aparece en la combinación ganadora.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me ha funcionado :)

Comment: Una pregunta Patricio el premio por acierto es de 20€ como lo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Actualice el código, dando 20 dolares por acierto, saludos

Comment: Muchas Graciass

Answer (score 0):

Si no entendí mal la pregunta, cada match con el array de la combinacion ganadora al array que a apostado se suma premio.

Entonces dentro del `for`

```
public int comprobarAciertos(int[] apuesta, int[] combinacionGanadora) {
 for (int i=0;i<apuesta.length -1;i++) {
     if ( apuesta[i] == combinacionGanadora[i] ) {
        premio++
        }
}
boolean reintegro = (apuesta[5] == combinacionGanadora[5]);

return premio;
}
```

Comment: he puesto todo el código que tenia arriba que no lo habia puesto por que al poner todo lo que me has puesto me sale error de IndexOutofBounds

Comment: Prueba ahora, que el for estaba mal puesto la igualdad, y en el booleano del reintegro es 5 no 6 ya que la longitud de tus arrays es de 6.